# Xcode doesn't run app on devices but simulator. dyld: Library not loaded, Reason: image not found

Tags: iphone, macos, dynamic, xcode7, ios9.3

I am trying to run an open source project on my Xcode to my devices.
The app runs normally on simulator. But has fatal error when running on a device.

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /Users/Kevinscience/cerbero/dist/ios_universal/lib/libspiceglue.0.dylib
>   Referenced from:
>   /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/317EAAE1-F492-44DE-B4BB-68B222E73C44/flexVDI.app/flexVDI
>   Reason: image not found (lldb)

Please help me to solve this problem.